# How to get Integer value from res/integers.xml?

Tags: android, xml, integer

Following is  my `integers.xml` file,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <integer name="LOCATION_ALARM_INTERVAL">60000</integer>
    <integer name="MID_NIGHT_ALARM_INTERVAL">86400000</integer>
</resources>
```

if it was `strings.xml`, i could have access variable like below,

```
getString( R.string.<variable_name> );
```

but how can I do same to get value from integeres.xml file ?

when I write `getResources().getInteger(R.integer.` it is showing me 3 variable which I haven't declared.

> [image]

So How can I access the variable which I declared in `integers.xml` file ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're looking at the `android.R.integer` instead of `your.namespace.R.integer`.

Eclipse probably imported the wrong one; it does that sometimes, it's rather annoying.

Go to your imports at the top of the file and remove:
`import android.R;`

Then you should be able to use the quick-fix to add the correct import.

Answer (score 36):

It should be done like this:

```
Resources res = getResources();
int i= res.getInteger(R.integer.int_value);
```

where int_value is the variable name given in your xml

Answer (score 8):

May be you have to clean your project once before accessing these file. I do it like this and it always works.

```
Resources r = getResources();
int i = r.getInteger(R.integer.<variable_name>)
```

Try to clean your project and restart your eclipse because this is the right way of doing it.

Comment: Try to change some layout file and then clean your project , i checked it twice its working here !

Comment: I tried those things already, but it was problem it importing correct R.java file, which is now solved. +1 for your effort dear.

Comment: Resources not Resource

Answer (score 6):

simple code :

```
int maximum = getContext().getResources().getInteger(R.integer.maximum);
```